# Spring Security Custom Authentication Provider 403 response

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a simple custom authentication provider with Spring Security in a Spring Boot App, but its not working.

My Custom Auth provider is:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication a) {
      try{
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken u = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("usuario", "password", roles);
        return u;
      }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
      }
}

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And my Security config is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EntityScan(basePackages = "sirio.io.models")
public class AppConfiguration {

   @Configuration
   @Order(1)
   public static class ApiWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
       @Autowired
       private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
           http.antMatcher("/admin/**")
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest()
               .hasRole("USER")
               .and()
               .httpBasic()
               .and()
               .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
         }
   }
}
```

I have settled several breakpoints in the CustomAuthProvider and it have been called but i always get a 403 response in the browser

[EDIT]
Tried another type of Custom Auth Provider but with same result.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails ud, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat) throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String string, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat) throws AuthenticationException{
       List<GrantedAuthority> authoritys = new ArrayList<>();
       authoritys.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
      UserDetails ud = new User("usuario", "password", authoritys);
      return ud;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring has an abstract implementation for username/password authentication. Extend it to your required implementation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java

Comment: I've tried extending AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider but its not working.